# Handling CSRF/XSRF tokens with Angular frontend and Drupal 7 backend

Tags: rest, drupal, angularjs, drupal-7, csrf

I'm in the process of building a new AngularJS frontend for a Drupal 7 website. This is using the Services module with session-based authentication, across two domains using CORS. I am able to authenticate with Drupal, retrieve the user object and session data, and then get the CSRF token from the services module. What I'm having trouble with is setting all this up in the header so that subsequent requests are authenticated. I understand the overall concept but am new to both AngularJS and preventing CSRF attacks.

From what I have gathered reading about this set-up with AngularJS and RubyOnRails, there can be inconsistencies between platforms concerning what the token is named and how it is processed. There also seems to be a number of suggestions on how to set this token in the header. However, I'm having trouble in finding a solid example of how to get these platforms speaking the same language.

The only thing I'm doing with my $httpProvider in app.js is:

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

The login controller, in controller.js:

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', 'SessionService', function($scope, $http, $cookies, SessionService) {
    $scope.login = function(user) {
        //set login url and variables
        var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/service/default/user/login.json';
        var postDataString = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(user.username) + '&pass=' + encodeURIComponent(user.password);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data : postDataString,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var sessId = data.sessid;
            var sessName = data.session_name;
            $cookies[sessName] = sessId;

            var xsrfUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com/services/session/token';
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: xsrfUrl
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"] = data;
                SessionService.setUserAuthenticated(true);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error loading xsrf/csrf');
            });
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var msgText = data.join("\n");
                alert(msgText);
            } else {
                alert('Unable to login');
            }
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution has to do with how the cookies need to be set and then passed through subsequent requests. Attempts to set them manually did not go well but the solution was simpler than I expected. Each $http call needs to set the options:

```
withCredentials: true
```

Another change I made was to use the term CSRF instead of XSRF, to be consistent with Drupal. I didn't use any built-in AngularJS CSRF functionality.

Comment: its been long since this answer was posted. but is there any chance you can give a example on how you making further subsequent request ? I am struggling wih this. I can login and store all user session details plus token (sending back cookie and X-CSRF-Token). but every further request I make to drupal , it returns 'user is not logged in' error.

Answer (score 2):

```
        addItem: function(data)
        {
            return $http.post('api/programs/'+$stateParams.id+'/workouts', {item:data},{
                headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="xxtkn"]').attr('content')

                }
            });
        }
```

since it has been a year of this topic! not sure still encountering the same problem but for the ones who comes to search for answers here is how i handle it!
Pay attention the headers{} part i define a new header and call it X-CSRF-Token and grab value from the DOM of (serverside) generated html or php. It is not a good practise to also request the csrf token from the server.Cuz attacker could somehow request that as well. Since you save it as a cookie. Attacker can steal the cookie! No need to save it in a cookie! send the token with header and read it in the serverside to match it!

and for multitab of a same page issue. I use the same token thruout the whole session. 
Only regenerate on login,  logout and change of major site or user settings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great library callse [ng-drupal-7-services](https://github.com/BioPhoton/ng-drupal-7-services). If you use this in you project it solves authentication / reauthentication and file / node creation aut of the box and you can fokuse on the importent stuff in your project.

So Authentication is there solved like this:

```js
function login(loginData) {
  //UserResource ahndles all requeste of the services 3.x user resource.
  return UserResource
  .login(loginData)
  .success(function (responseData, status, headers, config) {
    setAuthenticationHeaders(responseData.token);

    setLastConnectTime(Date.now());
    setConnectionState((responseData.user.uid === 0)?false:true)
    setCookies(responseData.sessid, responseData.session_name);
    setCurrentUser(responseData.user);

    AuthenticationChannel.pubLoginConfirmed(responseData);
  })
  .error(function (responseError, status, headers, config) {
    AuthenticationChannel.pubLoginFailed(responseError);
  });

};

(function() {
'use strict';


  

AuthenticationHttpInterceptor.$inject = [ '$injector'];

function AuthenticationHttpInterceptor($injector) {
 
   
    var intercepter = {
     request  : doRequestCongiguration,
    };
    
    return intercepter;

    function doRequestCongiguration (config) {
        var tokenHeaders = null;
 
        // Need to manually retrieve dependencies with $injector.invoke
        // because Authentication depends on $http, which doesn't exist during the
        // configuration phase (when we are setting up interceptors).
        // Using $injector.invoke ensures that we are provided with the
        // dependencies after they have been created.
        $injector.invoke(['AuthenticationService', function (AuthenticationService) {
            tokenHeaders = AuthenticationService.getAuthenticationHeaders();
            
        }]);

        //add headers_______________________
        
        //add Authorisation and X-CSRF-TOKEN if given
        if (tokenHeaders) {
            angular.extend(config.headers, tokenHeaders);
        }
        
        //add flags_________________________________________________
        
        //add withCredentials to every request
        //needed because we send cookies in our request headers
        config.withCredentials = true;

        return config;
    };
```

There is also some kind of kitchen sink for this project here: [Drupal-API-Explorer](http://www.drupalionic.org/explore/#/app/home)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each platform has their own convention in naming their tokens.

Here is a small lib put together hoping to make it easy to use with different platforms. This will allow you to use set names and could be used across all requests. It also works for cross-domain requests.

https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-csrf-cross-domain